# How to use R functions search and objects to find all possible R builtin functions related to normal distribution?

Tags: r

When I use the search function, it will come like below so how to find the normal distribution search and objects function?

```
search()[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats" 
        [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
        [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"       
        [10] "package:base
```

Comment: what does this have to do with ruby? Did you mistag the question?

Comment: are you looking for `?distributions'?